# Setting a different color for each tab using the same style

Tags: wpf, dynamic, static, resources, styles

So I have the following style in my Window.Resources:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="tiS">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Grid Height="40" Width="186">
                        <Border Name="tiBorder" Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              TextBlock.FontSize="20"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="90"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource tiB}"/>
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,-4,0,-4"/>-->
                            <Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tiLineFade}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="80"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="tiBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource tiLineFade}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This style is used on 5 TabItems, each with a different color given by 'DynamicResource tiB' in the trigger.

In each TabItem I have the following resource placed (Color1 is set in the Window.Resources):

```
<TabItem.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="tiB" Color="{StaticResource Color1}"/>
</TabItem.Resources>
```

I was wondering, is there an easier way to do this or am I doing it right? This is the first time I'm working with styles in WPF so I want to do it right. (This code is working! Looking for a better (if there is one) solution to my situation.)

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/igwxgp6M

Comment: Use style selector to apply the color...

Comment: I did a search on the style selector and from what I read is that I have to make different styles with the color in it and write some code to use the right style for each tabitem. The reason why I did it my way above is so I don't have to edit 5 different styles if I wanted to change something but only 1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.ItemsContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="TabItem">
          //Put triggers here
       </Style>
    <TabControl.ItemsContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Probably, but this doesn't give me less code in the TabItems themselves and if I wanted to change something I have to edit each trigger. Now I only have to change 1 style. I might be annoying but I'm looking for confirmation if my example is the right way to do it, what I did is working.